# Scrolling Views in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scroller that I would like to be able to scroll between Views like for example simple Image views like so.  I set them up here:

```
    UIImageView *settingsView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [settingsView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];

    UIImageView *cameraView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [cameraView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]];
```

Next I want to take those ImageViews and place them into my ScrollView array.  I tried doing it like this:

```
int PageCount = 2;
NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:settingsView,cameraView,nil];
UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[scroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
scroller.bounces = NO;
scroller.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scroller];
int width=scroller.frame.size.width;
int xPos=0;
for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
{
    UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
    [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
    xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```

The error I am getting is `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

How can i place those View's inside of the scroller?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:settingsView,cameraView,nil];
```

should be

```
NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@:"1.jpg", @"2.jpg",nil];
```

You were passing`UIImageView` object into what should be `NSString`

Comment: well actually I want to pass the UIImageView.  I know I need to edit the ImgView down below but how can I format this to be able to pass the UIImageView instead of just the picture?

Answer (score 0):

`arrImageName` already have `imageViews` ready.

So this line is wrong

```
[ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
```

you just need to add those `imageviews` to the `scrollview`.

```
for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
{
    [scroller addSubview:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
    xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```

and also consider setting frames to imageViews.

**Hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing a `UIImageView` to `imageNamed` instead of an `NSString`

This line:

```
[ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
```

Should be:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [arrImageName objectAtIndex:i];
[ImgView setImage:imageView.image];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int PageCount = 2;
NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:settingsView,cameraView,nil];
UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[scroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
scroller.bounces = NO;
scroller.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scroller];
int width=scroller.frame.size.width;
int xPos=0;
for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
{
    UIImageView *ImgView = [arrImageName objectAtIndex:i];
    [ImgView setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width,  scroller.frame.size.height)];

    [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
    xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
{
UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
ImgView =[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i];
[ImgViewSetFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0,   scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)]
[scroller addSubview:ImgView];
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```